# Как удалить подсветку Label в Menu?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В меню вставлен Label. Подсвечивается голубым цветом. Как удалить подсветку?

```
<Grid>
    <Menu>

        <Menu.Resources>

        </Menu.Resources>

        <MenuItem />
        <MenuItem  />
        <MenuItem />

        <Label  Content="label1111111111111111"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40"  >

        </Label>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Grid>
    <Menu>

        <Menu.Resources>

        </Menu.Resources>

        <MenuItem />
        <MenuItem  />
        <MenuItem Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}" />

        <Label  Content="label1111111111111111"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="40" Style="{DynamicResource LabelStyle1}"  >

        </Label>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

style

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>


<Style x:Key="LabelStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!--Цвет при наведении мыши -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                        <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--Цвет при нажатии мыши -->
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>-->

                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
            <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="LightYellow"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="LightYellow"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
            <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
        <!--Цвет при нажатии мыши -->
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Setter  Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
            <Setter  Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
        </Trigger>

        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="False"/>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

удалось у MenuItem отключить подсветку при наведении но так же для Label не работает:
на втором отключилась подсветка но также нельзя сделать у label (у неё нету IsHighlighted)

```
<MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="False"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Label, помещенный в меню, оборачивается в MenuItem и эта подсветка – часть его стиля, вам нужно поправить этот стиль

Comment: Автоматически создаю стиль MenuItem . копирую. `Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplateMy}"` в Label но ошибка - стиль не подходит

Comment: Покажите что вы сделали

Comment: Label  не внутри MenuItem  а внутри Menu

Comment: Все элементы внутри меню *автоматически* оборачиваются в MenuItem

Comment: а как сразу на всех распространить стиль или сделать только к Label

Comment: `<MenuItem Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"><Label>...</Label></MenuItem>`

Comment: а вариант без добавления Label в MenuItem есть?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте вообще не пихал Label  в меню, зачем вам это? Ну и не пойму, чем не устраивает вас описать MenuItem явно, если вы это не сделаете, то фреймворк сделает это за вас. Ну и я написал как решить вашу задачу, вы же почему-то отвергаете это решение

Comment: Потому что при добавлении стиля (`Style="{DynamicResource MenuItem1}"`) в MenuItem не отображается внутри него Label

Comment: Ага, понял, он делается дочерним пунктом, чтобы Label был заголовком, надо писать так: `<MenuItem IsEnabled="False"><MenuItem.Header><Label Content="label1111111111111111" TextBlock.Foreground="Black"/></MenuItem.Header></MenuItem>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<MenuItem IsEnabled="False">
<MenuItem.Header>
<Label Content="label1111111111111111" TextBlock.Foreground="Black"/>   
</MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```